# Recursive functions in clojure

Tags: function, recursion, clojure

How does this recursive function work step by step:

```
(fn foo [n]
  (if (< n 10)
    [n]
    (conj (foo (quot n 10))
          (mod n 10))))
```

I have problem with understanding: lets say i give it as `n` the number 123, and it will return a vector of its digits. At the last step when arrived to `1` and `(< 1 10)` it should go to the then-part `[n]`, return [1] and come out of the recursion. So this doesn't happen, what am i missing in the play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the last step when arrived to `1` and `(< 1 10)` it does go to the then-part `[n]`, return [1], but it does NOT *come out of the recursion*, only out of the innermost invocation.

The evaluation goes as follows:

```
(foo 123)
(conj (foo 12) 3)
(conj (conj (foo 1) 2) 3)
(conj (conj [1] 2) 3)
(conj [1 2] 3)
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: i see. My problem was that i was thinking upon reaching the `(foo (quot n 10))` it goes back to the starting point of the function and thus i was not seeing it in terms of bunches of nested `conj`s.